# Navigating 2D arrays by category?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Once again, I'd like to thank everyone for their prompt responses to my previous Gradebook question. I am now further along in the project, and have hit a (in my opinion) thornier problem.

The instructions call for me to create a function with this prototype:

```
int set_assignment_score(Gradebook *gb, char name[MAX_NAME_LEN], char a_name[], int score);
```

Once again, it will enter the Gradebook structure through the *gb pointer, but this time, it is meant to access the Scores array:

```
int scores[MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS][MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS]
```

... and deposit the "score" integer inside a specific cell for further use. The two **Char** parameters are important, because later on I will need to retrieve each specific integer from the Scores array and match it up with its precise name and a_name in a print_gradebook function.

I would love to share what code I have so far, but the fact of the matter is that I barely know where to start. I think that the key, however, is knowing how to navigate an integer array using **char** name and **char** a_name in place of the usual [i] and [j].

Any suggestions, advice, mockery, or requests for clarification are welcome. Please.

Here is the Gradebook structure:

```
typedef struct gradebook {
  int number_of_students;
  Students students[MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS];
  int number_of_assignments;
  char assignment_names[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS][MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
  int scores[MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS][MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS];
} Gradebook;
```

EDIT: Thanks, everyone! Combining your advice, I came up with this:

```
int set_assignment_score(Gradebook *gb, const char name[MAX_NAME_LEN], const char a_name[], int score) {
int i, j;

for(i=0; i< MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS; i++) {
if(strcmp(gb->students[i].name, name) == 0) {

  for(j=0; j< MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS; j++) {
    if(strcmp(gb->assignment_names[j], a_name) == 0) {
   gb->scores[i][j] = score;
 }

   }
 }
}

printf("%d\n", gb->scores[i][j]);
return 1;

}
```

I suspect it's a lot clumsier than it needs to be, but it gets the job done. Funnily enough, the printf function I put in to test it doesn't provide the result I want (I guess I'm printing the address or something?), but the actual function **does**.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work, but it's something. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oop - sorry. Went back and read the instructions. Said we're not allowed to create new structs. We can only use the ones the teacher outlined.

Comment: I just looked at your other question. You've already got all of the pieces in the `gradebook` structure. But it's a little different than I described. The index into the `students` array is the same index you would use in the `scores` array. Likewise for the `assignment_names` array.

Comment: Loop through the `students` array, comparing the student name to the `name` parameter. When you find a match, save the index and break out of the loop. Then use that index to access `scores[]`.

Comment: Well... that's cryptic, but it does give me hope. Be right back.

Comment: You need to post the `Gradebook` structure here. Don't make everyone go searching for your last question to understand this one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the general idea. The reason the `printf` doesn't work is because the loops continue running after you've found the matching student name and assignment name. So after the loops are done, you've lost the values of `i` and `j`. In fact, after the loops are done, `i==MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS` and `j==MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS`.

To keep the values of `i` and `j`, you should `break` from the loop when you find the matching name.  (I also added some error checking to handle the case where one or both of the names aren't found.)

```
int set_assignment_score(Gradebook *gb, const char name[MAX_NAME_LEN], const char a_name[], int score)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i< MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS; i++)
        if(strcmp(gb->students[i].name, name) == 0)
            break;

    for(j=0; j< MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS; j++)
        if(strcmp(gb->assignment_names[j], a_name) == 0)
            break;

    if ( i == MAX_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS || j == MAX_NUMBER_OF_ASSIGNMENTS )
    {
        printf( "unable to set score (i=%d, j=%d)\n", i, j );
        return 0;
    }

    gb->scores[i][j] = score;
    printf("%d\n", gb->scores[i][j]);
    return 1;
}
```